# showing exception on declaring new data member in class file using petapoco data access framework

Tags: petapoco

I am using petapoco dataaccess framework, after declaring one new parameter in class file according to database table i am getting the exception below mentioned, in windows service at starting the service.

Service cannot be started. System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String projectname.Models.EmailTemplatePOCO.get_Subject()'.
   at EmailService.EmailService.StartEmailService()
   at EmailService.EmailService.ScheduledService() in d:\Project\Projectname\trunk\projectname\EmailService\EmailService.cs:line 85
   at EmailService.EmailService.OnStart(String[] args) in d:\Project\projectname\trunk\projectname\EmailService\EmailService.cs:line 66
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

Answer (score 0):

Does your poco use properties? It will need to eg;

```
public string Subject {get; set;}
```

Not sure if you're getting a petapoco error or not